# Изменить изображение в pictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

Надо сменить изображение в pictureBox по нажатию на кнопку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на label это изображение должно сменить другое 
Главные вопросы:
1. Как изменить изображение в событии клика
2. Надо ли предварительно импортировать файл в PictureBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пропиши в обработчике события клик

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("someFile.jpg");
```

Учти что нужно использовать

```
using System.Drawing;
```